# How to use object properties in an array that matches objects in another array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an array with urls called "urls" that i want to match with the url on another array called "arrayConst" and then apply the header and the image that correspond to that url in my if-statement but this code seems only to apply the first header on index[0] instead of the header that correspond to that url. What am i doing wrong?

```
let findRecentPosts = setInterval(function () {
 const arrayConst = [
        {
            header: "​​XYZ",
            url: "url1",
            image: "url(https://....jpg)",
        },
        {
            
            header: "​ABC",
            url: "url2",
            image: "url(https://....jpg)",
        
        },
       
    ];
   
    const urls = ["url1", "url2", "url3"];
    

    
    if ($(".l-blog__sidebar").length > 0) {
        clearInterval(findRecentPosts);
        $(".c-related-single").each(function (i) {
            $(this).find("a").attr("href", urls[i]);
            $(this).find(".c-related-single__header").text(arrayConst[i].header);
            $(this).find(".c-related-single__image .c-background-image").css("background-image", arrayConst[i].image);
        });
    }


}, 1000);
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimout(function () {
        clearInterval(findRecentPosts);
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: `array` is not defined and the values of `urls` doesn't match anything in `arrayConst`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find` method of array to find the element from the other array.

```
let findRecentPosts = setInterval(function () {
    arrayConst = [
        {
            header: "​​XYZ",
            url: "https...",
            image: "url(https://....jpg)",
        },
        {
            
            header: "​ABC",
            url: "https...",
            image: "url(https://....jpg)",
        
        },
       
    ];
   
    const urls = ["url1", "url2", "url3"];
    

    
    if ($(".l-blog__sidebar").length > 0) {
        clearInterval(findRecentPosts);
        $(".c-related-single").each(function (i) {
            const url = urls[i];
            const otherURLProperties = arrayConst.find((u) => u.url === url); // returns the matching element

            $(this).find("a").attr("href", url);
            $(this).find(".c-related-single__header").text(otherURLProperties.header);
            $(this).find(".c-related-single__image .c-background-image").css("background-image", otherURLProperties.image);
        });
    }


}, 1000);
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimout(function () {
        clearInterval(findRecentPosts);
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but sadly it did not work. It still does not provide the right header and image for the found url.

Comment: Yes, I just updated it, it should be `u.url` in the find.